# Should I use strikethrough while the article revision?

Tags: peer-review, formatting, review-articles

I got an email from a reputed journal of Taylor & Francis pointing to the Major Revision of our systematic review article. As an author, I started the revision work by colouring the revised text "Red" and striking through the discarded texts. Now the problem is if I use strikethrough, then neither the word count nor the numbering of headings changes. What do you suggest as altruists? Should I include the strikethrough texts just to show the reviewers that we have made significant changes or just remove them for good?

NB: They mentioned not to use the "Track Changes" function because their system doesn't support that at this moment. And I'm using MS Word to format the manuscript.

Comment: Use the markup function.

Comment: I forgot to mention that they prohibited to use the "Track Changes" because their system doesn't support this at this moment.